# Java multi-threading synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning synchronization in java. Got struck in the below sample code today.

In the below code, *test()* method is made synchronized. So, I assume *th1*'s *test()* invocation would complete and then *th2*'s *test()* invocation would start. However, it is not happening that way. The outputs are interweaved. Can you please help me understand why ?

```
public class MyThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SampleThread sample = new SampleThread("one");
        Thread th = new Thread(sample);
        th.start();

        SampleThread sample2 = new SampleThread("two");
        Thread th2 = new Thread(sample2);
        th2.start();
    }
}



class SampleThread implements Runnable
{

    public SampleThread(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }

    String name;


    @Override
    public void run() {
        test();
    }

    public synchronized void test()
    {
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(name + "--" + j );
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To sync threads you need common point to sync them. Create object, pass it to the threads, then you can `syncronize` on the object. If you need to `wait` on the object in first thread, and `notify` in second. [First example](https://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/) from google.

Answer (score 0):

The method test() is synchronized but it isn't invoked by multiple threads cause each thread has a distinct instance of SampleThread. Use a single SampleThread for both threads to get subsequent output.

```
public class MyThread {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final SampleThread sample = new SampleThread();

    Thread th = new Thread(sample);
    th.start();

    Thread th2 = new Thread(sample);
    th2.start();
  }
}


class SampleThread implements Runnable {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    test();
  }

  public synchronized void test() {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + "--" + j);
    }
  }
}
```